# Foreign key conditions in sailsjs Waterline ORM

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I have defined two models like below, what i need to do is to retrieve the unique neighborhoods that belong to active partners (partner.status=1), i can retrieve the grouped neighborhoods like this

```
Locations.find({groupBy: [ 'neighborhood' ],sum['id']}, function(err,locations){});
```

and then match against a retrieved list of active Partners or backwards (ie first getting the active partners with the locations for each partner and pushing them to an array after verifying they are not already in there) or just by a custom sql query (which i am trying to stay away from)
but... i want to know if there is some kind of way to do it with the ORM as i have seen **model.find().populate('model')** doesn't accept parameters beyond the desired model not the where in the find method accept foreign keys conditions.

```
     Partner:{
        attributes:{
         businessName:{
             type:'string'
             },
         status:{
             type:'INT'
          }
          locations:{
              model:'Locations'
              via:'partner_id'
           }
          }
      }
Locations:{
    attributes:{
         partner_id:{
             model:'Partners',
             type:'INT'
             },
         neighborhood:{
             type:'STRING'
          }
          }
      }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? If so, it would be interesting to answer your own question as many people (like me) are looking for that!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for?

```js
Locations.find({where: {value1: key1}})
 .populate('partners', {where: {value2: key2}})
 .exec(function(err, locations){
     // Now you've got what you need
 });
```

P/S: Please checkout SailsJS v0.10.x documentation on GitHub. Personally I use this: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/tree/0.10
The documents are not up-to-date though :-)